# How do I fix this TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've wanted to do a Guess The Number fun command, and when I typed it all in, it gave me an error... It's a little strange seeing the error when I can't see any problem...
Here is the code:

```
const guildNumber = new Map();
const guildAttempts = new Map();
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

function guildNumberMap(message) {
    const guildId = message.guild.id;

    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20000) + 1;
    if (!guildNumber.get(guildId)) {
        guildNumber.set(guildId, number);
    }
}

function guildAttemptsMap(message) {
    const guildId = message.guild.id;
    if (!guildAttempts.get(guildId)) {
        guildAttempts.set(guildId, { attempts: 1 });
    } else {
        guildAttempts.get(guildId).attempts++;
    }
}

exports.run = async(message, args, client, Discord, MessageEmbed) => {
        const { member, channel, guild } = message;

        const provideaguess = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#F30B04')
            .setDescription(`**❌ Please provide a guess!**`)

        const pickinganumber = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#33F304')
            .setDescription('**Picking a number between 1 and 20000**')



        await guildNumberMap(message);
        await guildAttemptsMap(message);

        let guess = args[0];
        if (!guess && guildAttempts.get(guild.id).attempts === 1) {
            return channel.send(pickinganumber)
        } else if (!guess) {
            return channel.send(provideaguess);
        }

        if (+guess === guildNumber.get(guild.id)) {
            let attempts = guildAttempts.get(guild.id);

            const guessedthenumber = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#33F304')
                .setDescription(`✅ Perfect, <@${member.id}>the number was ${guildNumber.get(guild.id)}, it only took you ${attempts.attempts} attempts!`)

            channel.send(guessedthenumber);
            guildNumber.delete(guild.id);
            guildAttempts.delete(guild.id);
            

            return;
        } else if (+ guess < guildNumber.get(guild.id)) {
            return message.reply(`${guess} Is too low!`);
        } else if (+guess > guildNumber.get(guild.id)) {
            return message.reply(`${guess} Is too high!`);
        } else {
            return message.reply("Invalid number please try again");
        }
};
```

And I've tried so many things, I've tried consting MessageEmbed, I've tried putting MessageEmbed in the async.
Here is the error I get:

```
((node:16052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at guildNumberMap (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\commands\gtn.js:7:35)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\commands\gtn.js:37:15)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\index.js:28:14)
    at Client.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\e and f bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16052) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer, just another code:
Try using and re-coding that into your problem.

```js
var guesses;
var num = 0;

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    var mes = message.content.split(" ");
    if(message.content == '!pick') {
        message.reply('Picking a random number between 1 and 100');
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        guesses = 0;
    }
    if(mes[0] == '!guess') {
        if (num == 0)
        {
            message.reply('Picking a random number between 1 and 100');
            num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            guesses = 0;
        }
        else if(mes[1] == num)
        {
            guesses++;
            message.reply('You got it! Only took ' + guesses + ' tries.');
            message.reply('Picking a random number between 1 and 100');
            num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            guesses = 0;
        }
        else if(mes[1] < num)
        {
            message.reply(mes[1] + ' is too low');
            guesses++;
        }
        else if(mes[1] > num)
        {
            message.reply(mes[1] + ' is too high');
            guesses++;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: No problem, in any cases you can text me dm on discord: wolfie#2038

Answer (score 0):

You currently have imported the MessageEmbed class directly, while using the Discord namespace. You should use this instead:

```js
const guildNumber = new Map();
const guildAttempts = new Map();
const Discord = require('discord.js')

function guildNumberMap(message) {
    const guildId = message.guild.id;

    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20000) + 1;
    if (!guildNumber.get(guildId)) {
        guildNumber.set(guildId, number);
    }
}

function guildAttemptsMap(message) {
    const guildId = message.guild.id;
    if (!guildAttempts.get(guildId)) {
        guildAttempts.set(guildId, { attempts: 1 });
    } else {
        guildAttempts.get(guildId).attempts++;
    }
}

exports.run = async(message, args, client) => {
        const { member, channel, guild } = message;

        const provideaguess = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#F30B04')
            .setDescription(`**❌ Please provide a guess!**`)

        const pickinganumber = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#33F304')
            .setDescription('**Picking a number between 1 and 20000**')



        await guildNumberMap(message);
        await guildAttemptsMap(message);

        let guess = args[0];
        if (!guess && guildAttempts.get(guild.id).attempts === 1) {
            return channel.send(pickinganumber)
        } else if (!guess) {
            return channel.send(provideaguess);
        }

        if (+guess === guildNumber.get(guild.id)) {
            let attempts = guildAttempts.get(guild.id);

            const guessedthenumber = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#33F304')
                .setDescription(`✅ Perfect, <@${member.id}>the number was ${guildNumber.get(guild.id)}, it only took you ${attempts.attempts} attempts!`)

            channel.send(guessedthenumber);
            guildNumber.delete(guild.id);
            guildAttempts.delete(guild.id);
            

            return;
        } else if (+ guess < guildNumber.get(guild.id)) {
            return message.reply(`${guess} Is too low!`);
        } else if (+guess > guildNumber.get(guild.id)) {
            return message.reply(`${guess} Is too high!`);
        } else {
            return message.reply("Invalid number please try again");
        }
};
```

Comment: You did fix the, type error, but now I got a new one... 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

MessageEmbed() is a constructor, so it has to be properly exported

like this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
```

or try using this:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

^ if you have properly defined Discord like `const Discord = require('discord.js')`

Comment: It also give me a Type error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Yeah, sure, but it's another problem, so open another question for this or properly edit this one. Then I will help you.

Comment: I can write another guess command and you can use it if you want.

Comment: I would be more than happy if you could do that.